# set password for public android maven repo

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

I would like to find a elegant way to share android closed-source library with particular users using maven repo.

I have a closed-source library that only distribute to small groups of people. Currently, I have to manually drop the artifacts to each of them and not able to leverage the beauty of gradle and maven repo.

Is there a way to make my artifact in public repo but set a password or something similar, only people with my permission can download that from public maven repo?

Comment: Have you tried [Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) ?

Comment: best option is to use a repository manager as @Melchizedek suggested...